# How to generate random matrices that satisfy Lyapunov equations

Tags: matrix-equations, control-theory, random-matrices

I wish to generate a large number of matrix quadruples $(A,B,C,D)$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 2}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times n}$ and $ D \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ that satisfy
$$
A+A^T = -BB^T = -C^TC, \quad D^TD = I.
$$
The condition is similar to Lyapunov equation with the unknown set to identity.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The condition for D is just to be orthogonal and that's easy to generate, specially for a 2x2 case. Maybe you can remove that from the question to make it simpler

Comment: Just generate some random $B$. You need to choose the distribution of the elements of $B$ of course. Then set $C=B^{\top}$. Next, set $A = -BB^{\top}/2$. Finally, look up how to generate random unitary (rotation) matrices.

Comment: @Calculon You can of course always add any skew symmetric matrix to your expression you gave for $A$.

Comment: @Calculon, I think setting $A = -BB^T/2 + A_{skew}$ covers enough of the possible state matrices that it can be used as a testing tool. Thanks.